# How to give an object as parameter to an object, when two important variables are missing?

Tags: java

in this ShoppingCart program where i need to fill an array with all the 4 products i wonder how i can manipulate the amount which is added or removed from the cart, when the main-method calls the constructor "addItem" in the class "Item" and gives it an object as parameter with 5 variables and only 3 variables are "accepted" because it is an "Item" object and not an "Grocery" or an "Article" object and "Item" objects only can have 3 parameters.

```
public class ShoppingMall {

public static void main(String[] args){

    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Ihr digitaler Warenkorb:");

    boolean loop = true;
    int item = 0;
    String action = "";
    int pckg;
    float amount = 0.0f;



    ShoppingCart basket = new ShoppingCart();

    while (loop) {
        System.out.println("\nWelcher Artikel soll bearbeitet werden");
        System.out.println("------------------------------");
        System.out.println("1 Butter");
        System.out.println("2 Milch");
        System.out.println("3 Draht");
        System.out.println("4 Fliesen");           
        System.out.println("\nSie haben den Einkauf abgeschlossen?\nWaehlen Sie zwischen: ");
        System.out.println("------------------------------");
        System.out.println("5 Warenkorb ausgeben");
        System.out.println("0 Exit\n");
        System.out.print("Ihre Eingabe bitte: ");

        try{
            item = Integer.valueOf(input.readLine());


            if((item < 5) && (item > 0))
            {
                //System.out.println("\n------------------------------");
                do{
                    System.out.print("Waehlen Sie + fuer hinzufuegen oder - fuer entfernen. ");
                    action = input.readLine();
                }while(!action.equals("+") && !action.equals("-"));
            }

            //if(action.equals("+") || action.equals("-"))
            //{
                switch (item) {
                    case 1: {
                        System.out.print("Wieviele Packungen Butter ? ");
                        pckg = Integer.valueOf(input.readLine());
                        Grocery groc = new Grocery(1,"Butter",1.59f,20180618,pckg);
                        if(action.equals("+"))
                            basket.addItem(groc);
                        else
                            basket.removeItem(groc);
                        break;
                    }
                    case 2: {                        
                        System.out.print("Wieviele Packungen Milch ? ");
                        pckg = Integer.valueOf(input.readLine());
                        Grocery groc = new Grocery(2,"Milch",1.09f,20180618,pckg);
                        if(action.equals("+"))
                            basket.addItem(groc);
                        else
                            basket.removeItem(groc);
                        break;
                    }
                    case 3: {
                        System.out.print("Wieviele laufende Meter (lfdm) Draht? ");
                        amount = Float.valueOf(input.readLine());
                        Article art = new Article(3,"Draht",0.36f,"lfdm",amount);
                        if(action.equals("+"))
                            basket.addItem(art);
                        else
                            basket.removeItem(art);

                        break;
                    }
                    case 4: {

                        System.out.print("Wieviele Quadratmeter (qm) Fliesen ? ");
                        amount = Float.valueOf(input.readLine());
                        Article art = new Article(4,"Fliesen",20.00f,"qm",amount);
                        if(action.equals("+"))
                            basket.addItem(art);
                        else
                            basket.removeItem(art);

                        break;
                    }
                    case 5: {
                        System.out.println("\nIn Ihrem Warenkorb befindet sich:\n");
                        System.out.println("Artikel     Menge         Preis/Einheit             Preis");
                        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------");
                        System.out.println(basket);
                        System.out.print("\nWeiter mit beliebiger Taste!");
                        input.readLine();
                        break;
                    }
                    case 0: {
                        loop = false;
                        System.out.println("\nProgramm beendet");
                        break;
                    }   
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Ihre Eingabe wurde nicht erkannt!\n");

                }
            //}
            //else
            //  System.out.println("Ihre Eingabe wurde nicht erkannt!\n");

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("\nFalsche Eingabe:\nLebensmittel werden nur in ganzen Packungen abgegeben!\n"
                               + "Non- Food Produkte auch in Bruchteilen der jeweiligen Einheit\n"
                               + "Geben sie eine ganze Zahl bei Lebensmitteln ein oder eine \n"
                               + "Gleitpunktzahl bei Non- Food Produkten.");
        }
    }       
}
```

"Item" class

```
public abstract class Item {

protected int pid; //eindeutige Produktkennzeichnung
protected String signifier; //Name des Produkts, z.B. Butter
protected float pricePerUnit; //Preis pro Einheit

Item(){}

Item(int pid, String signifier, float pricePerUnit){
    this.pid=pid;
    this.signifier=signifier;
    this.pricePerUnit=pricePerUnit;
}



int getPid() {
    return this.pid;
}
String getSignifier() {
    return this.signifier;
}
float getPricePerUnit() {
    return pricePerUnit;
}
void setPricePerUnit(int newprice) {
    this.pricePerUnit=newprice;
}

public String toString() {
    return "This is the Base Class";
}

abstract public void addItem(Item toAdd);
abstract public void removeItem(Item toRemove);
abstract public String getUnit();
abstract public boolean isEmpty();
abstract public float getPrice();
```

"Article" class

```
public class Article extends Item {


float draht;
float fließen;
String unit;
float amount;
```

// sorry every code that i put in here is not formated right, i don´t know where the problem is.

There is on more constructor for Article with a super-constructor call in "Item" and also adding "this.unit=unit;" and "this.amount=amount"; to it

and a AddItem- method I don´t know how to work with, because there is ad AddItem-method in "Item" already.

```
public class ShoppingCart {

public static Item[] cart;
int temporary;
private int capacity;

public ShoppingCart() {

}

 public void addItem(Item toAdd) {



     if(toAdd instanceof Grocery) {

         if(toAdd.pid==1) {


             cart[0]=new Grocery(toAdd.pid, toAdd.signifier, toAdd.pricePerUnit);
             Grocery.packetCount+=((Grocery) toAdd).packetCount;
             System.out.println(cart[0]);
         }


         if(toAdd.pid==2) {


         }
     }

     if(toAdd.pid==3) {

     }
     if(toAdd.pid==4) {

     }
 }

 public void removeItem(Item toRemove) {
     //Waren entfernen/Menge reduzieren
 }
```

Comment: What is addItem in Item supposed to do? Sounds more like a Cart method.

Comment: addItem is supposed to add an object in the array Item[]. For example: Item[0] = new Grocery(toAdd.pid, toAdd.signifier, toAdd.PricePerUnit) but actually the object in the array should have 5 attributes. That is my problem.

Comment: Well the problem is that if a cart has 10 items, how do you know which of those you can do .getDraht() on? You can still use addItem() with a Article but you will not be able to access its additional properties without doing a if(item instanceof Article) first.

Comment: Ah i forgot to attach the shoppingCart. Now it is hopefully a bit clearer. Yes i tried it with instanceof.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your question then, what is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: In the addItem method in ShoppingCart, why are you creating a new object from the one sent to the method instead of adding the sent one directly to the array?

Comment: It now says cart cannot be resolved or is not a field, I tried now cart[0]=toAdd; that seems to work except that one error. But the other thing is, that i need to fill the array with 5 variables not only 3 like i do when i fill it with the parameter object toAdd (because Item only has 3 variables)